# How to save and read Cookie in Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies, key-value

**I save my cookie as the following code:**

```
public static void SetCookie(string key, string value, int expireDay = 1)
{
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(key , value);
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(expireDay);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

**The cookie values when stored are as follows:**
[image]

Read Cookie:

```
public static string GetCookie(string key)
{
        string value = string.Empty;

        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie.Value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            value = cookie.Value;
        }

        return value;
}
```

The problem is that when reading the cookie, **all the values are empty** according to the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum size of a cookie is 4kb.

Reference: https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/11912/common-concepts/cookies-support/cookie-limitations?v=20.1

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should read cookies from request header; not response!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(key)`.
You need to read it from the request. And write the changes to the response.

Here's a simpler working example, that simply prints "Hey!", and appends an exclamation on each GET:

```cs
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public string CookieValue = "Hey!";
        private const string COOKIE_KEY = "HEY_COOKIE";

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Request.Cookies.TryGetValue(COOKIE_KEY, out string? actualValue);
            if (actualValue is not null) CookieValue = actualValue + "!";

            // Only required since we're changing the cookie
            // TODO: set the right cookie options
            Response.Cookies.Append(COOKIE_KEY, CookieValue, new CookieOptions { }); 
        }
    }
```

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<h1>@Model.CookieValue</h1>
```

Also, while debugging things over HTTP, it's useful to also look at Chrome's network tab.

Comment: `var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(key)
            ? HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[key]
            : HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];` 
This condition checks both the **Response** and the **Request** @galdin

Comment: @MohammadSalmanian it "checks" the response. The expression before the `?` is the check.

Comment: updated post.`var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key];` @galdin

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you used HttpContext.Current.Response. Instead of this, you should declare a parameter in the SetCookie method like this: HttpContext context, then in the controller, when you call the method, you have to send HttpContext controller property as an argument.

```
public static void SetCookie(HttpContext context, string key, string value, int expireDay = 1)
{
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(key , value);
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(expireDay);
        context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

In the controller:

```
SetCookie(HttpContext, yourKey,yourValue)
```

You also should change your GetCookie method like this:

```
public static string GetCookie(HttpContext context,string key)
{
        string value = string.Empty;

        var cookie = context.Request.Cookies[key];

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie.Value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            value = cookie.Value;
        }

        return value;
}
```